# Is it a good practice to hold reference in network call interceptor of value that might change using Dagger2?

Tags: android, retrofit, dagger-2

I want to avoid adding to every network call token and locale parameters, but they are not constant and might change. To achieve that I want to use network interceptor. 
Locale string is taken from LocaleManager which holding reference to PreferenceManager... And UserManager has field token which is updated quite often from back-end.
Network modue:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
@QueryInterceptor
public Interceptor queryInterceptor(@UserLocale final String userLocale) {
    return new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(@NonNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();
            final HttpUrl url = request.url().newBuilder()
                    .addQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM_OS, ANDROID_OS)
                    .addQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM_VERSION, BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME)
                    .addQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM_LOCALE, userLocale)
                    .build();
            request = request.newBuilder().url(url).build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    };
}
```

Locale:

```
 @Provides
@UserLocale
public String userLocale(LocaleManager localeManager) {
    return localeManager.getCurrentLanguageCode();
}
```

and something similar with user token.

Is it a good practice to do so?

Sorry, Dagger2 is still quite new for me.

Answer (score 0):

Indded you should not store locale in graph since when configuration will change your locale will not be updated. You could have a "ConfigurationComponent" with its own scope but in your case  i'll just remove locale from graph :

```
@Provides
@Singleton
@QueryInterceptor
public Interceptor queryInterceptor(final LocaleManager localeManager) {
    return new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(@NonNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();
            final HttpUrl url = request.url().newBuilder()
                    .addQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM_OS, ANDROID_OS)
                    .addQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM_VERSION, BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME)
                    .addQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM_LOCALE, localeManager.getLocal())
                    .build();
            request = request.newBuilder().url(url).build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I am storing locale string in shared preferences as well, LocaleManager is basically is only a wrapper for getting string from preferences which is in LanguageModule.. in AppComponent, so after locale change interceptor receiving new stored string. What about if @QueryInterceptor singleton will hold reference to User's entity's Token field when used like locale string in example above? My concern and more clear question is - is it possibility to cause memory leaks when singleton instance have references to my LocaleManager and User?